# website gui - Double integrated drop-down list

Tags: drop-down-menu, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have seen something peculiar... a drop-down-list that has two single lists bound together. See [here](https://www.bytbil.com/bil?VehicleType=bil&Makes=&FreeText=&OnlyWarrantyProgram=false) the website about what I ment.

I've also added a image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEsqT.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80jaX.png) in case the website changes it appearance.

How is this done (language)? And where can it be downloaded?

Comment: show effort and check for clues on the webpage itself... in what is it made? HTML... version? Done in WordPress, etc.? Standalone program...? more info please.

Comment: https://www.bytbil.com/bil?VehicleType=bil&Makes=&FreeText=&OnlyWarrantyProgram=false

Comment: You'll get an answer via https://www.bytbil.com/kontakt.

Comment: Haha, ask the company?